# How to Compare Only Unique Observations Using Chi-Square Test in R

Tags: r

I have 2 datasets randomization(screen is secret number of Patient and group is for what group he belongs)

```
randomization=structure(list(screen = c("01-39", "01-26", "01-40", "01-01", 
"01-14", "01-06", "01-20", "01-34", "01-35", "01-42", "01-02", 
"01-41", "01-16", "01-36", "01-08", "01-10", "01-29", "01-38", 
"01-27", "01-15", "01-19", "01-13", "01-45", "01-03", "01-22", 
"01-11", "01-25", "01-07", "01-04", "01-30", "01-23", "01-12", 
"01-09", "01-28", "01-21", "01-44", "01-18", "01-31"), group = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-38L))
```

here 19 man in 1 and 19 man in the 2 group ,total=38.

second dataset people who have any AE (adverse event)

```
AE=structure(list(screen = c("01-001", "01-003", "01-003", "01-003", 
"01-003", "01-003", "01-003", "01-003", "01-004", "01-004", "01-004", 
"01-004", "01-004", "01-004", "01-004", "01-005", "01-005", "01-005", 
"01-005", "01-006", "01-006", "01-006", "01-007", "01-007", "01-007", 
"01-008", "01-008", "01-008", "01-008", "01-008", "01-008", "01-009", 
"01-009", "01-009", "01-009", "01-011", "01-011", "01-011", "01-011", 
"01-011", "01-011", "01-011", "01-012", "01-012", "01-012", "01-013", 
"01-013", "01-013", "01-013", "01-013", "01-013", "01-014", "01-014", 
"01-016", "01-016", "01-017", "01-018", "01-018", "01-018", "01-019", 
"01-020", "01-020", "01-020", "01-020", "01-020", "01-020", "01-020", 
"01-021", "01-021", "01-021", "01-021", "01-021", "01-021", "01-022", 
"01-022", "01-022", "01-022", "01-022", "01-023", "01-024", "01-024", 
"01-024", "01-024", "01-024", "01-024", "01-024", "01-025", "01-025", 
"01-025", "01-026", "01-026", "01-026", "01-026", "01-026", "01-027", 
"01-027", "01-027", "01-028", "01-028", "01-028", "01-028", "01-028", 
"01-029", "01-030", "01-030", "01-031", "01-031", "01-032", "01-033", 
"01-033", "01-033", "01-034", "01-034", "01-034", "01-034", "01-035", 
"01-035", "01-035", "01-035", "01-035", "01-035", "01-035", "01-035", 
"01-037", "01-037", "01-037", "01-037", "01-037", "01-037", "01-038"
), group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), AE = c("increase in lymphocytes", "increase in lymphocytes", 
"increase in abs. lymphocytes", "increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in abs. neutrophils", 
"decrease in neutrophils", "decrease in abs. Monocytes", "decrease in monocytes", 
"increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in hemoglobin", "decrease in neutrophils", 
"decrease in abs. monocytes", "increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in abs. monocytes", 
"decrease in red blood cells", "increased pancreatitis. Amylase", 
"lipase increase", "increase in basophils", "increase in basophils", 
"increase in abs. lymphocytes", "increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in neutrophils", 
"increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in neutrophils", "increase in lymphocytes", 
"increase in lymphocytes", "increase in lymphocytes", "increase in basophils", 
"increase in abs. Eosinophils", "increase in eosinophils", "increase in abs. basophils", 
"lipase increase", "decrease in monocytes", "decrease in abs. monocytes", 
"lipase increase", "increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in neutrophils", 
"increase in lymphocytes", "increase in abs. lymphocytes", "decrease in neutrophils", 
"increase in abs. eosinophils", "increase in eosinophils", "increase in eosinophils", 
"increase in abs. eosinophils", "increase in eosinophils", "increase in lymphocytes", 
"decrease in abs. monocytes", "increase in leukocytes", "decrease in lymphocytes", 
"increase in abs neutrophils", "increase in neutrophils", "increase in lymphocytes", 
"increase in abs. monocytes", "increase in alkaline phosphatase", 
"increase in basophils", "increase in eosinophils", "lipase increase", 
"lipase increase", "increase in alkaline phosphatase", "increase in lymphocytes", 
"increase in abs. lymphocytes", "decrease in abs. monocytes", 
"increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in monocytes", "lipase increase", 
"decrease in neutrophils", "decrease in abs. neutrophils", "decrease in monocytes", 
"increase in AST", "increase in ALT", "increase in lymphocytes", 
"decrease in neutrophils", "decrease in abs. monocytes", "increase in abs. lymphocytes", 
"increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in abs. monocytes", "decrease in monocytes", 
"increase in lymphocytes", "lipase increase", "decrease in monocytes", 
"decrease in abs. monocytes", "increase in abs. lymphocytes", 
"increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in neutrophils", "decrease in abs. monocytes", 
"decrease in monocytes", "increase in leukocytes", "increase in lymphocytes", 
"lipase increase", "increase in abs. Monocytes", "increase in ESR", 
"increase in leukocytes", "increase in abs. lymphocytes", "increase in abs. Monocytes", 
"lipase increase", "increase in alkaline phosphatase", "increase in basophils", 
"lipase increase", "increase in alkaline phosphatase", "increase in abs. lymphocytes", 
"increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in neutrophils", "increased glucose", 
"increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in neutrophils", "increase in basophils", 
"increase in basophils", "increase in lymphocytes", "increase in abs. lymphocytes", 
"increase in lymphocytes", "increase in CFC", "lipase increase", 
"increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in neutrophils", "increase in lymphocytes", 
"decrease in abs. neutrophils", "lipase increase", "increase in lymphocytes", 
"decrease in neutrophils", "increase in basophils", "increase in basophils", 
"increase in abs. lymphocytes", "lipase increase", "increase in lymphocytes", 
"decrease in monocytes", "increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in neutrophils", 
"decrease in monocytes", "decrease in abs. monocytes", "increase in lymphocytes"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -130L))
```

The same person may have several adverse events at once, so patient numbers may be duplicated.
But How can I count the unique number of patients with AEs in each group and compare the number of people with AEs between groups using the `chi square test` . Here 129 rows ,but in fact  in each of the two groups the same number of people with adverse events (17 people, as I counted).

I don't want to use the `prop.test` because I have to count by hand how much was originally in randomization. But I need automatically the first calculate how many people were initially  in randomization, and how many unique numbers are present in the list with adverse events and get the p-value of the `chi square`.
How o should perform it?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

AE %>% 
  count(group, screen) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  summarise(pval = chisq.test(group, n)$p.value)
```

```
       pval
1 0.1921088
```